# readr::parse_number with leading zero

Tags: r, numbers, extract, readr

I would like to parse numbers that have a leading zero.

I tried `readr::parse_number`, however, it omits the leading zero.

```r
library(readr)

parse_number("thankyouverymuch02")
#> [1] 2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

The desired output would be `02`

Comment: Let's be clear:  *numbers* do not have a leading zero.  *strings containing numeric characters* do .

Comment: what about octal?

Comment: Typically octals have to be  "0X123"  , but in any case, once again, a numeric value as stored in whatever language you are using, may be **displayed** as a string with a leading zero, but the number itself does not.   Your example is showing how to parse a **string** which contains number symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest and most naive would be:

```r
gsub("\\D", "", "thankyouverymuch02")
[1] "02"
```

The regex special `"\\d"` matches a single 0-9 character only; the inverse is `"\\D"` which matches a single character that is anything *except* 0-9.

If you have strings with multiple patches of numbers and you want them to be distinct, neither `parse_number` nor this simple `gsub` is going to work.

```r
gsub("\\D", "", vec)
# [1] "02"   "0302"
```

For that, it must always return a `list` (since we don't necessarily know a priori how may elements have 0, 1 or more number-groups).

```r
vec <- c("thankyouverymuch02", "thank03youverymuch02")
regmatches(vec, gregexpr("\\d+", vec))
# [[1]]
# [1] "02"
# [[2]]
# [1] "03" "02"

#### equivalently
stringr::str_extract_all(vec, "\\d+")
# [[1]]
# [1] "02"
# [[2]]
# [1] "03" "02"
```

Comment: marvellous. so a numeric value in `R` cannot have a leading `0`, correct? such a value has to be a string (sorry for missing some basics in `R`).

Comment: Yes. In some instances a leading 0 might indicate "octal", but in general leading `0`s are not retained.